# сессия добавить данные какому то пользователю

Tags: php, laravel

у меня щас такая ситуация:
я делаю интеграцию платежки из bitpay, после создания инвойса и оплаты клиентом этого инвойса там есть notificationURl по адресу которого туда придет оповещение в виде json о данных проведенного платежа.
Сделал контроллер под коллбек, туда приходит json, допустим он успешно проведен->деньги зачислены клиенту на баланс и ему предоставляется некая новая преференция в связи с оплатой.
Как оповестить юзера об успешной операции? сессия? но как записать сессию в определенного пользователя? Есть какие то идеи? (чтобы без дополнительных ненужных полей в базе данных хотел бы)
Данные id пользователя достаются из order.user_id по order.invoice_id из json. Айди пользователя есть.
Разрабатываю на laravel 5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Механизм сессий не очень подходит для решения данной задачи по ряду причин:

1. Как только завершится сессия (или пересоздастся), то вы потеряете данные пользователя, и он не сможет дальше использовать "некая новая преференция в связи с оплатой". А это зависит от настроек сервера и php, чем обычно управлять не дают.
2. Даже если вы упретесь и хотите работать именно через сессии, то без таблицы в бд вам все равно не обойтись, в которой вы будете хранить user_id и session_id. Что бы потом искать файл сессии и дописывать в него данные (не очень вариант)

Поэтому на вопрос `как записать сессию в определенного пользователя? чтобы без дополнительных ненужных полей в базе данных хотел бы` ответ никак

Я бы создал отдельную таблицу `payments`, где хранил бы все юзерские оплаты и статусы (успешно оплачено, не хватило денег и т.п.). А самого юзера оповещать можно:

- либо с помощью скрипта, который каждый раз при загрузке страницы смотрел бы в таблицу `payments`, и если есть успешные оплаты, то выводил бы информацию об этом
- либо на стороне клиента запускал периодически ajax запрос на проверку оплаты
- либо совсем заморочиться и сделать что нибудь типа [long polling](https://habrahabr.ru/post/128535/)

Comment: да, пришел к подобному заключению. Есть возможность проверить есть ли просмотры у данного "товара" - если нет, то буду показывать что данный товар не просмотрел даже сам создатель и его необходимо оформить. Спасибо